# Is this set open in the Euclidean topology on the plane?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $\mathbf{R}^2$ be the two-dimensional Euclidean space, and let $$ A := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbf{R}^2 | \, \, \, |x| < \frac{1}{y^2+1} \}.$$ Then how can we establish (preferably using the definition) if this set is open or not in the standard topology on $\mathbf{R}^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $ f(x,y)= |x|-\frac{1}{y^2+1} $ is a continuous function. Since $ A= f^{-1}(-\infty,0) $, then $ A $ is open.

Comment: user55449, thank you so much, but is there any way of showing this using only the definition of open sets (i.e. by showing that each point of this set is an interior point)?